# Python @cls.decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

I want to create a python decorator that adds a certain function to a list of functions of that class that will, sometimes, be processed. Example code:

```py
class A:

  # every subclass should define _list

  @classmethod
  def decorator(cls, f):
    # cls = B
    cls._flist.append(f)
    return f

  @classmethod
  def processFunctions(cls):
    for f in cls._flist:
      ...

class B(A):
  _flist = []

  @B.decorator # Obviously not possible because cls is not defined (yet)
  def foo(self):
    print("Inside foo")
```

Is it possible to replicate this behaviour? The class (cls) should be passed when decorating the function, so I can't use the usual approach of creating a wrapper function that "unpacks" cls and the other arguments.

Comment: Hold on ... is your `class A` already missing some `self`s? Should it be: `self._list = []` etc?

Comment: Why is `decorator` an instance method when it doesn't use `self` at all? Make it a static method (or standalone function) and use `@A.decorator` (`@decorator`) instead.

Comment: Methods don't belong to a specific instance, they're associated with the class as a whole.

Comment: The method definition happens once, when the class is defined, not every time you create an instance.  What do you mean by "special functions in this instance"?

Comment: Sorry, fixed code to add the missing selfs

Comment: Ok, so now where does this `_list` reside and how are you going to use it?

Comment: But with `@A.decorator` every subclass would have the same `_list`, with functions of other subclasses. And I can't use `@B.decorator` because B is not (yet) defined.

Comment: So you still need to explain how you are going to use this.

Comment: The list will be (sometimes) iterated, to do something with every function in that list. I updated the question and sample code.

Comment: You need an *instance* of `A`; the fact that `B` subclasses `A` doesn't magically give you an `A` instance.

Comment: Your use-case as described doesn't really match your example as written. If all you want is to iterate over a list of a (sub)class's methods, what's wrong with defining the class variable, `_flist = [foo_method, bar_method]` etc? No instance is necessary.

Comment: @Kache Yes, its true indeed that no instance is necessary. I just changed the example so it uses class methods instead.

Comment: Oh, well now I'm pretty sure that can be done with metaclasses.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I think I've worked something out.

You need an instance of `A`, but as a class variable inside `B`.

Then each method will need an instance:

```py
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self._flist = []

  def decorator(self, f):
    self._flist.append(f)
    return f

  def processFunctions(self, other):
    for f in self._flist:
      f(other)


class B:
  a=A()

  @a.decorator
  def foo(self):
    print("Inside foo")

  def processFunctions(self):
    B.a.processFunctions(self)

b = B()
b.processFunctions()
```

Output

```
Inside foo
```

Comment: great example of Composition over Inheritance - https://realpython.com/inheritance-composition-python/

Comment: I'm of the opinion that every time someone says that, it was always that inheritance would never have worked properly. There are always some situations that inheritance is better suited to.

Comment: of course there are exceptions. The principle comes from flexibility and explicitness. Inheritance has it's own unique features. This answer was instructive in showing one should keep both in mind if inheritance isn't working

Answer (score 1):

The following way is based on the implementation behavior of `locals()` in CPython but there is [PEP 558](https://peps.python.org/pep-0558/) to make it documented standard behavior:

```
class A:

  # every subclass should define _list

  @staticmethod
  def decorator(loc):
    def registrator(f):
      loc['_flist'].append(f)
      return f
    return registrator

  @classmethod
  def processFunctions(cls):
    for f in cls._flist:
      ...

class B(A):
  _flist = []

  @decorator(locals())
  def foo(self):
    print("Inside foo")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, like the one the package ABC uses is making the decorator add a flag to the function, and then go through the functions of this class that have that flag activated.

```py
class A:
  @staticmethod
  def decorator(f):
    def wraps(f)
      f.__processable__ = True
      return f
    return wraps

  def processFunctions(self):
    for d in dir(self):
      try:
        f = getattr(self, d).__func__
        if f.__processable__:
          f() # Or whatever we want to do with the function
      # Instead of try/except we could use a bunch of nested ifs
      except AttributeError:
        pass
```